# how to read single column data from realm database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, realm

I have one table with three column which named "Id,Name,Last Name". 
For get data of **Name** column in **sq-lite** we are using query like '**SELECT Name form table_name**' if we using **realm** in **"IOS"** then which method we have to use for get only one column data.

Please help me for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

One of the cool things about Realm is that all property reads are *lazy* -- that is, the value is only ever fetched when needed. So you can just do `[MyModel allObjects]` and if you only ever read the `name` property on the objects in that `RLMResults`, no other properties from the object will be fetched.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for one column retrieval in iOS.

```
RLMResults *allResults = [loginModel allObjects];
for(loginModel *login in allResults)
{
   NSArray *name = [login valueForKeyPath:@"userName"];
   NSLog(@"One column result----%@", name);
}
```

In our case `loginModel` is a Realm object name.